# How to define GPS module in Android?

Tags: java, android, linux-kernel, android-ndk, beagleboard

I'm porting android to Devkit8000 which is a BeagleBoard clone. I have a GPS module connected on /dev/ttyS0. I could successfully get NMEA output when writing "cat /dev/ttyS0" in the terminal emulator.

I want to know how to let android know that there is a GPS module on /dev/ttyS0 and it is outputting NMEA standard? To be able to use the android.location class with it! or test it with any GPS app in the store!

Is there something to edit in the android's source? adding driver for example, writing a code with android-ndk or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface you must implement is described in the [Platform Development Kit](http://pdk.android.com/online-pdk/guide/gps.html) and you may want to use the [source for the emulated GPS](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/hardware/libhardware_legacy.git;a=blob;f=gps/gps_qemu.c;h=5c0695170934d7fdb952a07029646ace71f02ad8;hb=HEAD) as a reference.